# One-point compactification of a condensed set

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, topos-theory, condensed-mathematics

Is there a notion of a 'one-point compactification of a condensed set'?

$\textbf{Motivation:}$ For a locally compact space $X$, there is a notion of maps that vanish at infinity. A continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ vanishes at infinity if, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a compact $K \subseteq X$ such that $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in X \setminus K$. The set of all continuous maps that vanish at infinity is naturally a Banach algebra. By letting $X^*$ be the one-point compactification of $X$, we can think of $C_0(X)$ as the continuous maps from $X^*$ to $\mathbb{C}$ with $f(\infty) = 0$.

I am trying to define what $C_0(X)$ would be for a condensed set $X$ using the definition of one-point compactification.

Comment: "Condensed" is too weak. It should rather be "everywhere condensed".

Comment: Even "everywhere condensed" is still too weak. The notion is perhaps : *the complements of nowhere condensed*.

Comment: @WlodAA it's not clear what you mean by "everywhere condensed". A condensed set is a small sheaf on the category of profinite sets, unless I have misread Luiz. The tag [condensed mathematics] implies this.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, to me an infinite subset, say $\ A\subseteq X,\ $ is condensed in $\ X,\ $ when $\ A\cap U\ $ is empty or has cardinality equal to $\ |X|\ $ for every $\ U\ $ open in $\ X.\ $ *** $\ A,\ $ is everywhere condensed in $\ X,\ $ when $\ A\cap U\ $ has cardinality equal to $\ |X|\ $ for every non-empty $\ U\ $ open in $\ X.\ $

Comment: @WlodAA That is a different usage of the word "condensed".

Comment: One-point compactifications aside, what you have in mind shouldn't work, morally, since already for topological/CGWH spaces $C_0(X)=0$ unless $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, so I think the answer to your question "What should $C_0(X)$ be for a general (non-locally-compact) condensed set?" is: 0.

Answer (score 2):

Given $T$ a functor from profinite sets to sets, one can probably just define the one-point compactification of $T$ to be the functor that takes $S$ to the disjoint union, over all open subsets $S_1 \subseteq S$, of the inverse limit, over subsets $S_2 \subseteq S_1$ that are clopen in $S$, of $T(S_2)$.

The idea here is that $S \setminus S_1$ is the inverse image of the one additional point, which should be closed, and $S_1$ should map to the complement.

If $T = \operatorname{Hom}(S,X)$ for a topological space $X$ then $\operatorname{Hom} (S, X^*)$ is the disjoint union over open subsets $S_1$ of $X$ of $\operatorname{Hom}(S_1, X^*)$, and since open subsets of profinite sets are increasing unions of clopen subsets, we can express $\operatorname{Hom}(S_1, X^*)$ as the inverse limit of $\operatorname{Hom}(S_2, X^*)$ so this definition recovers the one-point compactification in the case of topological spaces.

Checking that this satisfies the sheaf condition should be relatively straightforward although I admit I didn't write it down.

Comment: What does "that are clopen in $S$ of $T(S_2)$" mean?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Nothing, the "of" should attach to "inverse limit".

Comment: Ok, so $$\coprod_{S_1\subseteq S \text{ open}}\lim_{S_2\subseteq S_1\text{ clopen in } S}T(S_2)$$

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, exactly.

Comment: @WillSawin Interesting construction! I wonder if using this definition $X^*$ is quasicompact in the sense of definition 2.5 of complex.pdf notes.